# The code is compiled successfully but the func() is not being executed. Someone please suggest required changes

Tags: c, function, sockets

```
//SERVER SIDE SCRIPT for Diffie-Hellman using sockets.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 80
#define PORT 43461
#define SA struct sockaddr



char* itoa(int value, char* str, int radix) {
    static char dig[] =
        "0123456789"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int n = 0, neg = 0;
    unsigned int v;
    char* p, *q;
    char c;
    if (radix == 10 && value < 0) {
        value = -value;
        neg = 1;
    }
    v = value;
    do {
        str[n++] = dig[v%radix];
        v /= radix;
    } while (v);
    if (neg)
        str[n++] = '-';
    str[n] = '\0';
    for (p = str, q = p + (n-1); p < q; ++p, --q)
        c = *p, *p = *q, *q = c;
    return str; 
}

void func(int sockfd) 
{
    printf("hello"); //This statement is not being displayed and rest of the code not    executed
    char buff[MAX],uname[MAX],pass[MAX];
    int n,clen,a1,a2,b2,val,key;
    struct sockaddr_in cli;
    clen=sizeof(cli);

xx: 

    //RECIEVING USERNAME
    bzero(uname,MAX);
    recvfrom(sockfd,uname,sizeof(buff),0,(SA *)&cli,&clen);
    printf("Username received");
    //RECEIVING PASSWORD
    bzero(pass,MAX);
    recvfrom(sockfd,pass,sizeof(buff),0,(SA *)&cli,&clen);

    if(strcmp(uname,"admin") == 10 && strcmp(pass,"admin") == 10)
    {

        printf("Accepted");

        //RECEIVING NUMBER FROM CLIENT
        recvfrom(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0,(SA *)&cli,&clen);
        b2=atoi(buff);

        printf("Received from client\n");

        //GENERATING SERVER SIDE NUMBER
        a1=(rand() % 19) + 1; // Random value selected by Server
        a2=pow(7,a1);   
        a2=a2 % 11;   // Server Generating value to be sent G:7 , P:11

        //Sending the value-a2
        bzero(uname,MAX);
        itoa(a2,buff,10);
        sendto(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0,(SA *)&cli,clen);
        printf("Server side number sent\n");

        //GENERATING KEY AND THE DATA
        key=pow(b2,a1); 
        key=key % 11;       //                      G:7 , P:11
        val=key*1024;          //                       DATA: 7060

        //Sending the data required
        bzero(uname,MAX);
        itoa(a1,buff,10);
        sendto(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0,(SA *)&cli,clen); 
        printf("Data sent \n");     
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Incorrect Username-Password combination. Waiting for next try \n");
        strcpy(buff,"wrong");
        sendto(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0,(SA *)&cli,clen);
        goto xx;

    }
}


int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if(sockfd==-1)
    {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    if((bind(sockfd,(SA *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr)))!=0)
    {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d",sockfd);// This value is displayed in the output screen
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n");}
        func(sockfd);
        close(sockfd);
    }
```

When the script is executed, The binding is done successfully and the same message is displayed on the output screen. But the function call for func() is not executed.I do not get the first statement of the function call-'Hello' in the execution.Please suggest the changes required in this code.

Answer (score 3):

If `bind()` was successful then the `func()` will be called. The reason why you are not seeing your output is because `stdout` is usually buffered and it will flush it once the internal buffer is full.

Add `\n` to your debug `printf()` calls which will force it to flush the output.

```
printf("hello\n");
```

Similarly, other debug printf's. You could also use `fflush(stdout);` to flush `stdout`.

Obviously, you need to client code as server is waiting for it in your code.